# How to unset a nic's network namespace in Linux?

Tags: linux, networking

I know `ip link set tap0 netns XX` can attribute namespace `XX` to device `tap0` in Linux. But what should I do after that if I want to bring `tap0` back to the public(the unnamed one) namespace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we list the interfaces

```
[root@host ~]# ip link list
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:4e:ca:5c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: veth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
    link/ether e6:da:05:95:2f:4e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: veth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
    link/ether 4a:73:df:f1:87:26 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

We put device veth1 in netns testns

```
[root@host ~]# ip link set veth1 netns testns
```

we can verify it's in

```
[root@host ~]# ip link list
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:4e:ca:5c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: veth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
    link/ether 4a:73:df:f1:87:26 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

[root@host ~]# ip netns exec testns ip link list
1: lo: <LOOPBACK> mtu 65536 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
3: veth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
    link/ether e6:da:05:95:2f:4e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Then we put it back to default netns

```
[root@host ~]# ip netns exec testns ip link set veth1 netns 1
```

And we verify it's back in

```
[root@host ~]# ip netns exec testns ip link list
1: lo: <LOOPBACK> mtu 65536 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
[root@host ~]# ip link list
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:4e:ca:5c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: veth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
    link/ether e6:da:05:95:2f:4e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: veth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
    link/ether 4a:73:df:f1:87:26 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

You have to replace veth1 by tap0 in your case.
So in fact :

```
 [root@host ~]# ip netns exec testns ip link set tap0 netns 1
```